# Table dynamically populated from calculations from multiple tables

Tags: sql-server

I am currently working on the development of a Web-based application for a local company.(My senior project in college) I finally have the data how I want it, except for one table. This is a water usage tracking system which is dependent on a total allocation. So, as you can see in the pictures in the link provided, I have a large table with all the MapTaxLots that this company manages. Each MapTaxLot can have several types of land. Example) AcresAmountKID, AcresAmountKBID, AcresAmountWarren** Additionally, one customer can own many MapTaxLots. What I need to do, is fill another table with a total allotment that takes each type of acre in each MapTaxLot, and multiply it with the corresponding Multiplier from the small table in the images provided. Once all these calculations are made, I need to add all the calculations together for each customer for a total allocation into the empty table.

TL;DR: I need to multiply AcresAmountKID from large table by KID from small table for each MapTaxLot. I then do this for remaining AcreTypes. I then need to add all the values into one sum (allocation) for each customer and insert that calculation into the empty table. I apologize if this is hard to understand, but this problem is so unique and I've never done calculations from different tables in this way.

http://imgur.com/a/f8Oww

Comment: Which DBMS you're using MySQL or MS SQL SERVER? Use the appropriate tags...

Answer (score 0):

If I correctly understood your question, This is the query you want and this for MSSQL Server

```
insert into Allotment
select customerID, sum(
(select AcresAmountKID from land  where MapTaxID = ld.MapTaxID ) * (select MultiplierAmount from AcreMultiplier where AcreTypeID='KID')) + 
(select AcresAmountKBID from land where  MapTaxID = ld.MapTaxID ) * (select MultiplierAmount from AcreMultiplier where AcreTypeID='KBID')) +
(select AcresAmountWarren  from land where  MapTaxID = ld.MapTaxID ) * (select MultiplierAmount from AcreMultiplier where AcreTypeID='WARREN')) + 
(select AcresAmountGroupE  from land where  MapTaxID = ld.MapTaxID ) * (select MultiplierAmount from AcreMultiplier where AcreTypeID='GROUPE')) + 
(select AcresAmountRent  from land where  MapTaxID = ld.MapTaxID ) * (select MultiplierAmount from AcreMultiplier where AcreTypeID='RENT')) +
(select AcresAmountCalD  from land where  MapTaxID = ld.MapTaxID ) * (select MultiplierAmount from AcreMultiplier where AcreTypeID='CALD')) ), TotalAllocation
sum((select AcresAmountKID  from land where  MapTaxID = ld.MapTaxID ) * (select MultiplierAmount from AcreMultiplier where AcreTypeID='KID')) remainingAcreTypes, 
Null 
from Land ld where group by customerID
```

Comment: Hey, I very much appreciate the response! I'm not sure I asked the question very well. I tried pasting this into a query and am confused slightly. I need to combine all acre types such as KID, KIBID, Warren, etc into one large sum which is placed into Allocation(Allotment) when multiplied by each corresponding multiplier. Here is what I have now, and I am just curious what the second SUM is for. Again, thank you for your help!

Comment: Here is the link to the query I have now with correct Table names. However, I'm unsure of the second sum and the remaining AcreTypes.        http://imgur.com/YSBXhqk

Comment: can you check this now?

Comment: I checked it with these new results. Can you explain the second sum to me as well? http://imgur.com/reSLQDt

Comment: What do you meent by Second sum?

Comment: First one is for Total_amount column. and the second one is for remaining_amount column. is there anything wrong?

Comment: These are the errors that I have now imgur.com/reSLQDt

Comment: But the screen, you've shared in imgur.com/reSLQDt is my old code.

Comment: did you mean second sum is remaining_amount ?

Comment: When I said remaining AcreTypes, I just meant all of the AcreTypes which you included in the first sum. Do you know why I may be getting the errors?